# reserved word NUMBER used as column name causing error with Cursor declaration

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors, database-cursor, reserved-words

... at least I think that is the problem.

I am writing a function which contains a cursor declaration that access a table where one of the column is the reserved word NUMBER (yeah, I know..). The function hit a problem at compile time:

Error(16,10): PL/SQL: ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated ORA-06553: PLS-488: invalid variable declaration:  object 'NUMBER' must be a type or subtype

MY code looks something like:

```
CURSOR my_cur 
IS 
    SELECT "NUMBER", col2, col3
    FROM tb1_x;
```

To make sure that is the problem, I changed the code to

```
CURSOR my_cur 
IS 
    SELECT 'NUMBER', 'col2', 'col3'
    FROM dual;
```

and it compiled alright, but obviously that's not what I want.

Unfortunately, I don't have the option to change the column name(sigh), and for the record

```
    SELECT "NUMBER", col2, col3
    FROM tb1_x;
```

works OK in normal SQL execution.

Anyway I can work around this problem? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: grasping at straws here...but have you tried `select "NUMBER" as NUMBER` or `select "NUMBER" as 'NUMBER'` or something like that?

Comment: @gangreen I don't think it would work.. Actually, the cursor declaration will failed at compile time as long as the table tb1_x is used, even the culprit column "NUMBER" is not being access at all. Like the below, will fail:`CURSOR my_cur 
IS 
    SELECT col2, col3
    FROM tb1_x;`

Comment: I solve the problem. By creating a View to wrap around the culprit table, renaming the column "NUMBER" as NBR in the View. Then the Cursor can be declared using the View and column NBR, without mentioning the original table nor "NUMBER". Compiled ok and worked fine.

Comment: Can you create a view based on tbl_x with the `NUMBER` column renamed to "Num" (or something), then `select Num as NUMBER from view`?

Comment: Ok, cool. Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

We can also create record as well as uses column in cursor.fetching of data from cursor i surprising for me as i dint used this before .

```
Create table temp2("number" integer,id integer,name varchar2(200));
insert into temp2 values(1,1,'Gaurav Soni'); 
insert into temp2 values(2,2,'Niharika Saraf');
Commit;


DECLARE
  type abc is record(
  "number" number,
   id       NUMBER,
   name     varchar2(200));

 v_rec abc;
 TYPE v_cur IS REF CURSOR;

 cur    v_cur;
 v_temp INTEGER;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR
     SELECT "number", id, name FROM temp2;
 LOOP
   FETCH cur  INTO v_rec;
    EXIT when cur%notfound;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('number is ' || v_rec."number");
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('id is ' || v_rec.id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('name is ' || v_rec.name);

  end loop;
CLOSE cur;

end;
```

**output**

```
number is 1
id is 1
name is Gaurav Soni
number is 2
id is 2
name is Niharika Saraf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table temp2("number" integer);
insert into temp2 values(1); 
insert into temp2 values(2);
insert into temp2 values(3);
commit;

DECLARE
TYPE v_cur IS REF CURSOR;

cur      v_cur;
v_temp   INTEGER;
BEGIN
OPEN cur FOR
  SELECT "number"
  FROM   temp2;
FETCH cur
INTO  v_temp;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('number is ' || v_temp);
CLOSE cur;
```

END;

**output**

> number is 1
>
> I am not able to replicate this issue ,but this is workign fine for me

Comment: @this is also compiling when i am creating procedure or function

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The structure of your Cursor declaration is a bit different from mine. Can you try this:

```
drop table temp2;
Create table temp2("NUMBER" integer );
insert into temp2 values(1); 
Commit;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_dummy VARCHAR2(10) := '';

CURSOR cur1 IS
    SELECT *  FROM temp2;

BEGIN    
    FOR a_rec IN cur1
    LOOP
      l_dummy := 'dummy';    
    END LOOP;

    RETURN l_dummy;

END func1;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

The above hit compilation error. Just change the 2nd line to get rid of the reserved word I manage to get it compiled. BTW I am using Oracle SQL Developer client connecting to Oracle 10.2 db.

```
Create table temp2("NUMBERxxx" integer );
```